# how to set a field for an function object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

[image]

[image]

I want to set a field which is called `__times` of a Function object. But I got an error in vs-code.

Please tell me what is the appropriate way to do that?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26368 (since TS 3.2).

Comment: "Function" is typescript interface. it has only "name" property. but interfaces you can override globally. or as in answer abou.

Answer (score 2):

> But I got an error in vs-code.

Simplest way I can think of removing the error, add `& {__times?:number}`

## Complete example

```
let getCountableWrapper = (func: Function & {__times?:number}) => {
  return func.__times = 0;
}
```